# How to read posted xml data/response from android, posted in Yii controller/action

Tags: php, android, yii

I am trying to read xml response that is posted by android application for my webservices.

I am trying the code as below

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) && !empty($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])) {
            $input = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
        } else {
            $input = "hello";
        }
```

but i got null to value input,

please help me out, if you have any solution or example over the internet.

Comment: Check with the var_dump() function at yii wheather you get the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your application post data based on the request? Better call that url through curl and then var_dump( curl response) , that will make sure you are getting back something. If still having problem let me know.

thanks

Comment: I want to get POST data request by Android application using the following method.
String response = HttpPostRetreiver.retriver(url,input, LoginScreen.this);  Please check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169107/how-to-post-data-from-android-to-yii-framework-server-getting-error is same the error. I think you can get better understanding what I am seeking.

Comment: I had checked all posible variable from which request may come but getting nothings, the andorid application hit the controller/action nicely only thing is that the data from android application is in xml formate and I am unable to trap that response.